# HTML5 text area to only accept numbers

Tags: html, reactjs, textarea

For `<input>` we can use `type=number` and it lets user only enter number.

Is there anyway to do this for `textarea`?

I'd appreciate some inputs on the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the textarea to only hold numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571923/how-to-limit-the-textarea-to-only-hold-numbers)

Comment: @Tushar Shahi I did check that out and it doesn't really answer to my exact question :( most of them gave answer to `input` but not `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the same as using input, eitherway, input should be easier for you, and dont see a reason why you want to use textarea instand of input. But here is a soulution if you wannt to use textarea.

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<span style="color:red" id="errmsg"></span>
```

**Js**

```
$("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        $("#errmsg").html("Numbers Only").show();
               return false;
    }
});
```